# React Native - Get initial route when App is opened from a notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm using react-native and onesignal to handle notification.

If you press the notification when the app is in the background, i'll catch the `'opened'` event, and redirect to the correct route (in the notification metadata)

But when the app is closed, the click on the notification just opens the app, without firing the `'opened'` event.

How can i fetch the initial pressed notification metadata ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [RNFirebase Cloud Messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage), you can use the proper listener `getInitialNotification`  where you can catch when the notification is opened while the app is closed. Follow that guide [Notifications - Handling Interaction](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction) for more infos.

Comment: I'm not using firebase but onesignal for notification, it'll still work the same ?

Comment: @AbelChalier honestly, I never used onesignal, but all those stuffs works almost the same, so it should have a notification listener too. I gave a quick look at [onesignal mobile push documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) and if you look at the example at **step 5**, it shows some code with handlers, like `OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler`, I think this is what you are looking for